# Calculate the discrete density of the variables of a Markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, markov-chains

$X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables of Bernoulli with parameter $\frac{2}{3}$.

$Z=X+Y$

$\{X_n\}_{n \in  \mathbb{N}}$ with values in {0,1,2} having $Z$ such as initial law and the transition matrix :

$$Q=\begin{bmatrix}0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} & 0 &\frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

a. Calulate $E[ZX]$ and $Var[Z-2Y]$

 b. Calculate the discrete density of the variables $X_0$, $X_1$ , $X_2$

 c. Calculate $E[X_2]$ and $Var[X_1]$

 d. Calculate the invariant probability measure

$ X \sim B(1, \frac{2}{3}) $ and $ Y \sim B(1, \frac{2}{3}) $

$$E[X^2+XY]=E[X^2]+E[X]  E[Y]=E[X^2]+\frac{4}{9}$$
$$E[X^2]=Var[X]+E[X]^2=\frac{2}{3} \ \frac{1}{3}+ \frac{4}{9}= \frac{2}{3}$$
$$E[X^2+XY]=\frac{10}{9}=E[ZX]$$

$$Var[X-Y]=Var[X]+Var[Y]=\frac{2}{9} + \frac{2}{9}=\frac{4}{9} $$

How can I make the next steps?

Examining all the possibly cases of $Z$ values:

$$P(Z=0)=P(X=0, Y=0)=\frac{1}{9}$$

$$P(Z=1)=P(X=1, Y=0)+P(X=0, Y=1)=\frac{1}{3} \ \frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3} \ \frac{2}{3}= \frac{4}{9}$$

$$P(Z=2)=P(X=1, Y=1)=\frac{4}{9}$$

So, I have calculate the probability measure: $\mu=(\frac{1}{9}, \frac{4}{9}, \frac{4}{9})$ of $X_0$

$X_1$:

$$(\frac{1}{9}, \frac{4}{9}, \frac{4}{9}) \bullet (0, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})=\frac{4}{9} $$

$$(\frac{1}{9}, \frac{4}{9}, \frac{4}{9}) \bullet (\frac{1}{2}, 0 , \frac{1}{2})=\frac{5}{18} $$

$$(\frac{1}{9}, \frac{4}{9}, \frac{4}{9}) \bullet (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, 0 )=\frac{5}{18} $$

$X_2$:

$$Q^2=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} \\ \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2} &\frac{1}{4} \\ \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$$

$$(\frac{1}{9}, \frac{4}{9}, \frac{4}{9}) \bullet (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4})=\frac{10}{36} $$

$$(\frac{1}{9}, \frac{4}{9}, \frac{4}{9}) \bullet (\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2} , \frac{1}{4})=\frac{13}{36} $$

$$(\frac{1}{9}, \frac{4}{9}, \frac{4}{9}) \bullet (\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2} )=\frac{13}{36} $$

$$E[X_1]=0 \ \frac{4}{9}+ 1 \ \frac{5}{18}+ 2 \ \frac{5}{18}=\frac{15}{18}$$

$$E[X_1^2]=0 \ \frac{4}{9}+ 1 \ \frac{5}{18}+ 4 \ \frac{5}{18}=\frac{25}{18}$$

$$Var[X_1]=\frac{25}{18}-\frac{225}{324}=\frac{225}{324}$$

$$E[X_2]=0 \ \frac{10}{36}+ 1 \ \frac{13}{36}+ 2 \ \frac{13}{36}=\frac{13}{18}$$

d. The invariant probability measure: $\rho \ Q=\rho$

\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2} \ y + \frac{1}{2} \ z=x \\
\frac{1}{2} \ x + \frac{1}{2} \ z=y \\
\frac{1}{2} \ x + \frac{1}{2} \ y=z \\
x+y+z=1
\end{cases}

So, $\rho=(\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3})$

Is it correct?

Thanks!

Comment: This is the answer for the distribution of $X_0$. Now to the distributions of $X_1$ and $X_2$...

Comment: @Did is it correct?

Comment: Seems so. $ $ $ $